# Project name, description and technologies from Apps & Software are not in the pdf export

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, export

I just created a couple of entries under the "Apps and Software" section on Careers. I filled out everything for each entry (Project Url, Project Name, Project Description, Technologies and Your Role/Contribution).

When I export to pdf now, these entries are included, but I only see the Project Url and my Role/Contribution. I don't see the Project Name, or the Project Description, or the Technologies.

This seems to be a bug, as in the Show/Hide Sections dropdown at the top, there's a possibility to uncheck those projects, but they have empty titles:

[image: section dropdown]

**Edit:** I just tried to work around this problem by creating the entries under the "Open Source" section as "other...", in stead of under the "Apps & Software" section, but the issue remains the same. Although there are other projects there, who are actually coupled with a supported open source site (github, codeplex, ...) and these are rendered fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yo, I fixed your problem.  What's up.

Comment: Best... answer.... ever!

Comment: +1 Best bug-fix message I've seen in a long time. No fluff, just reality.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much, sir.